# Window resize not working in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, window-resize

I have written following code to be executed when window is resized. But whenever I resize my window everything disappear from screen. It all blank.

```
function onWindowResize(){
   console.log("on window resize");

   if ( camera.name == "Orthographic_Camera" ){
       camera.left = window.innerWidth / - 2;
       camera.right = window.innerWidth / 2;
       camera.top = window.innerHeight / 2;
       camera.bottom = window.innerHeight / - 2;
   }

   if ( camera.name == "Perspective_Camera" ){
       camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
   }

   camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
   camera.lookAt(scene.position);

   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth / window.innerWidth );

   //render();
}
```

Comment: Is it the perspective or orthographic camera causing the problem?

Comment: @2pha both of them does not work.

Comment: code looks ok to me except the camera.name check, camera name is "" by default make sure you set the camera up with that name or use camera.type or instanceof

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Are you sure your camera is looking where you expect after calling camera.lookAt() ? I have never really had to call this in my resize hanflers (probably because my cameras usually point to 0,0,0)

Comment: @2pha there are no errors in console. This time i tried only with perspective camera. I have camera.aspect, camera.updateProjectionmatrix and renderer.setSize inside this function and it still does not work. However i can see the "on window resize" line getting printed.